# TexStudio `Error: Could not start the command: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "file_name".tex`

Tags: texstudio

I just start to use texstudio, seems better than texmaker, however while compilation it gives following error:

```
Error: Could not start the command: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "file_name".tex
```

does anyone knows how to solve this? or why does it happen? Thanks.

Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit

Here is the texstudio version in case that I installed wrong one:

TeXstudio 2.7.0 (hg 4323:cf7f5964517f)
Using Qt Version 4.8.1, compiled with Qt 4.8.2 R

Comment: do you have tex installed? (texstudio is only an editor)

Comment: yes I was using texmaker without any problem. I can compile the file through terminal (Im just trying to compile a file that I already did with texmaker) thus it should have compile it perfectly unless something missing

Comment: Try to specify the path to pdflatex explicitly at Options -> Commands. Depending on how the PATH variable is configured on your os and on how you start TXS it might not receive the information where pdflatex is located (console and UI applications may have different settings for this).

Comment: I have reinstalled the tex because it was broken as I understand, I tried everything. Now the problem have been fixed but it asks for new packages (I installed all tex took 5 hours) such as `Error: File `beamer.cls' not found` or `Error: File `appendix.sty' not found` thus how can I install all such files in order to not have any problems again? Thanks.

Comment: now im trying `./install-tl --gui=perltk` its installing some more files. Is there any think that I should do additionally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As advised above I checked the tex directory which was broken due to some changes I made in my computer. Thus I install it again by using the codes provided in texlive website which lead me to a partial installation, so it gave different errors. I install the full texlive package by using

```
   `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`
```

If you are facing with very same problem do not forget to remove the texlive directory before installation which is in `/usr/local/texlive/2013/`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As *root*, take the LaTeX full name:

```
$ which latex
/opt/texbin/latex
```

(LaTeX is Ok!)

Start TexStudio and select: *Options* > *Configure TexMaker*

Now modify the 2nd line including path `/opt/texbin/`:

```
(PdfLaTex)  /opt/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Done!

(Should work in TeXStudio 2.8.2.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same error (for example on a different operating system), this can be the generalized solution to the problem:

> 1.a or why does it happen?

1.b It can happen caused because you installed a LaTex Editor[1] without having installed a LaTex Compiler[2]. (That is how I got the error, the first comment, by @David Carlisle, implicates something else than just the Latex Editor (for example TexStudio or Texmaker) could be required.)

> 2.a does anyone knows how to solve this?

2.b If 1.b is indeed the case, then it can be solved by installing the/a Latex Compiler.
I believe the commands above explicitly do that in Linux, in Windows the Latex Compiler Texlive as mentioned by the answer of @Jackaraz can be installed by going to:

https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html

And downloading and installing:
http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-windows.exe

After that, the Latex Editor Texmaker automatically finds the Latex Compiler Texlive, even if you change the installation drive from: `C:\texlive\2018` to `E:\texlive\2018`.

[1] In simple terms: software in which you can type and edit Latex documents.

[2] In simple terms: software for (helping in) converting your typed or edited text, made in the Latex Editor into, for example, a `.pdf` file.

Ps. I am unsure whether this is off-topic, please let me know if so. It provides a general solution to the error and neglects the additional info that it is in Unix, since that was already answered in the answers above. I thought answering it here would keep StackExchange a little more coherent.